# What is the best way to setup a test user for a Microsoft teams app in a closed B2B platform

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

we are running a trading B2B platform were we cannot create testing accounts on a production environment.
Currently we are trying to submit an app to the Microsoft teams catalog, the submission process asks for test credentials to be used to test the app and the connection to the platform alongside the manifest file. however we can only provide sandbox test accounts, which will obviously cannot be used in the production app, and are hosted under different links.

in the manifest to be submitted we setup the production links for the app that needs to be submitted to the store.

The question here is how is this usually handled? how should we provide a sandbox test accounts and a production manifest at the same time for the app submission process?

Comment: As rightly pointed by Hilton, you need to provide demo tenant account details which App Submission team. You can [get a free Teams developer tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/prerequisites?tabs=vscode#get-a-free-teams-developer-tenant-optional) which you can use for this. Here is specific on what app submission needs: [Prepare your store submission - Accounts.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/submission-checklist#accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what Microsoft is asking for is credentials to a test Microsoft 365 **tenant**, where they can log in and install your app. Your app must for sure already be 100% "production" ready - live hosting etc., not a test setup behind the scenes.